# Javascript show/hide div with iframe inside works in everything but IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, iframe

This is the `javascript` code I'm currently using:

```
     function toggleContainer(containerID, hideContainerIDs) {
            if(hideContainerIDs) {
                for(var i=0; i<hideContainerIDs.length; i++) {
                    ajaxChat.showHide(hideContainerIDs[i], 'none'); 
                }
            }       
            ajaxChat.showHide(containerID);
            if(typeof arguments.callee.styleProperty == 'undefined') {
                if(typeof isIElt7 != 'undefined') {
                    arguments.callee.styleProperty = 'marginRight';
                } else {
                    arguments.callee.styleProperty = 'right';
                }
            }
            var containerWidth = document.getElementById(containerID).offsetWidth;
            if(containerWidth) {
                document.getElementById('chatList').style[arguments.callee.styleProperty] = (containerWidth+28)+'px';
                document.getElementById('chatBooth').style[arguments.callee.styleProperty] = (containerWidth+28)+'px';  
            } else {
                document.getElementById('chatList').style[arguments.callee.styleProperty] = '20px';
                document.getElementById('chatBooth').style[arguments.callee.styleProperty] = '20px';
            }

        }
```

The DIV and IFrame Code:

```
<div id="chatBooth" style="display:none; overflow: hidden;"> 
        <iframe style="overflow:hidden;height:100%;width:100%" height="100%" width="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" name="booth" id="booth" src="about:blank">
        </iframe>
    </div>
```

I've tried everything I can think of, This code seriously works in every browser but `IE`. What it's doing is when you click on a link inside the window that is currently visible it loads a new page inside the hidden `IFrame`, and you can make said `IFrame` visible  with a button click. Here is the button to show and hide the hidden `DIV` and `IFrame`.

```
<input type="button" value="[LANG]toggleChat[/LANG]" title="[LANG]toggleTitleChat[/LANG]" alt="[LANG]toggleChat[/LANG]" onclick="ajaxChat.showHide('chatBooth', null);"/>
```

Here is the code for the `Link` that changes what should be located in the `IFrame` that works in every browser but `IE`!

```
alert(this.channelName);
            document.getElementById('booth').contentWindow.location.reload(true);
            document.getElementById('booth').src = 'http://www.cnn.com';
```

The Above code works in everything but `IE`. I'm at a total loss. I've spent hours scouring `Google` and can't seem to find a solution or even what is causing the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the showHide code requested:

```
showHide: function(id, styleDisplay, displayInline) {
    var node = document.getElementById(id);
    if(node) {
        if(styleDisplay) {
            node.style.display = styleDisplay;
        } else {
            if(node.style.display == 'none') {
                node.style.display = (displayInline ? 'inline' : 'block'); 
            } else {
                node.style.display = 'none';
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

The Codes used to Reload the Iframe and Change the Iframes SRC

```
document.getElementById('booth').contentWindow.location.reload(true);
document.getElementById('booth').src = 'http://www.WEBSITE.com'+ ajaxChatConfig.loginChannelName +'/index.html';
```

The Above doesn't seem to allow IE to load anything inside the IFrames even when its told to do so.

Comment: Have you got a working example for debugging? e.g. on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: can you post your ajaxChat.showHide code?

Comment: by 'not working' you mean that iframe is not loading or you're getting some errors?

Comment: No errors, Its just not displaying the Iframe at all, and i have a full working example if you'd like to take a look at it, But i'd prefer not to show.

Comment: what is ajaxChat? Is it a div or an iFrame or what?

Comment: It's an chat client variable.

Answer (score 0):

I copied the code that you have provided, and got it to work by simply changing one of your functions., However because I dont have the actual working copy of your code I cant be sure this will work for you...

I changed the showHide function decleration from this...

```
showHide: function(id, styleDisplay, displayInline) {
```

to this...

```
function showHide(id, styleDisplay, displayInline) {
```

the HTML I used:

```
<body>
    <div id="chatBooth" style="display:none; overflow: hidden;width:100%;">
        <iframe style="overflow:hidden;height:100%;width:90%;border:1px solid red;" scrolling="no" name="booth" id="booth" src="http://www.ebay.com"></iframe>
    </div>

    <input type="button" value="toggleChat" title="toggleTitleChat" onclick="showHide('chatBooth', null);"/>
</body>
```

Update::

you can use this function to replace document.getElementById('booth').contentWindow.location.reload(true);

```
function loadContent(passedInURL){
    if(!passedInURL){
        passedInURL = "http://www.ebay.com";
    }
    var theIFrame = "<iframe style='overflow:hidden;height:200px;width:90%;border:1px solid red;' scrolling='no' name='booth' id='booth' src='";
    theIFrame += passedInURL + "'></iframe>";
            document.getElementById('chatBooth').innerHTML= theIFrame;
}
```

and add this button to the page..

```
<input type="button" value="reLoad" title="reLoadFrame" onclick="loadContent();"/>
```

Comment: I see what you where doing there, The problem is I think it has to do with


document.getElementById('booth').contentWindow.location.reload(true);

document.getElementById('booth').src = 'http://http://www.WEBSITE.com'+ ajaxChatConfig.loginChannelName +'/index.html';

Comment: I added above the code in proper format, it doesn't appear to want to let me do it down here. But what it is doing is not allowing IE to reload the IFrame's SRC even when the page first loads.

Comment: a bit of a hack that seems to work is to replace the document.getElementById('booth').contentWindow.location.reload(true).

Comment: Instead of trying to reload the iframe, you can recreate/replace it by using...    document.getElementById('chatBooth').innerHTML= "<iframe style='overflow:hidden;height:100%;width:90%;border:1px solid red;' scrolling='no' name='booth' id='booth' src='http://www.ebay.com'></iframe>";

Comment: It should then be straightforward to use a variable as the src... See how u go.

Comment: check the update to my answer for the function and button to test it out